# Inflate a TableLayout from inside a LinearLayout from Inside a ScrollView

Tags: android

I would like to inflate an XML in `TableLayout` within a `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`.

This is my main.xml:

```
<ScrollView..>
  <LinearLayout>
    <TableLayout>
    </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this is my xml to inflate tabletoinflate.xml

```
<TableLayout>
</TableLayout>


tl1 = (TableLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1); //this exists in the onCreate
```

//this method is supposed to inflate, however it's not doing the job

```
void myMethodToInflate()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabletoinflate, null;
        initializeTogglesPost(view);
        tl1.removeAllViews();
        tl1.addView(view);
}
```

//This method initializes the 24 toggle buttons inside the TableLayout to inflate.

```
private void initializeTogglesPost(View viewPost)
{   
    toggleButtonsPost = new ToggleButton[24];
    for(int i = 0;i<24;i++)
    {
        toggleButtonsPost[i] = (ToggleButton)viewPost.findViewWithTag((String) ((i+1) + ""));
        toggleButtonsPost[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}
```